# VS MFC TRACE always output %d as 0

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to use TRACE in a thread to output an int value, but it always output 0:

```
UINT ThreadFunc (LPVOID pParam)
{
    for (int i =1;i<99;i++)
    {
        TRACE(TEXT("THREAD_RUNNING %d\n",i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `THREAD_RUNNING 0`. I use debugger and clearly see this `i` value is a valid number. I try to replace `%d` with `%u`, but the result is the same.

What could be wrong?

Comment: You give i as an argument to TEXT() and not to TRACE?

Comment: Yeah. You are right. it should be `TRACE(TEXT("THREAD_RUNNING %d\n"),i);` Problems solved. How strange. No errors or warnings are given.

Comment: I would expect a warning here:  "warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'TEXT'," and in a simple test I do get this warning.  Are you sure you don't have this warning disabled?